# How to call oracle stored procedure using mybatis (annotation based.)

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, mybatis

I need to call an oracle stored procedure in java using mybatis.The stored procedure and things so far i have tried is given below.

Stored Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_GET_ACCOUNT (INVAR_ACCOUNT IN DATE 
                                         , OUTVAR_CONFIG OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS begin
     OPEN OUTVAR_CONFIG FOR
          SELECT * from accounts; END P_GET_ACCOUNT;
```

To call this stored procedure i called the mapper

AccountImplMapper.java

```
@Select("{CALL P_GET_ACCOUNT(#{account, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}," +
                                     "#{result, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR})}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
AccountImpl selectAccount(@Param("account") String account,@Param("result") Object result);
```

The AccountImplMapper method is called in DatabaseImpl

DatabaseImpl.java:

```
AccountImpl = new AccountImpl();
accountImpl =  accountImplMapper.selectAccount("mark",accountImpl);
```

Where AccountImpl is the model class for my database table account.When i run this i am not able to get the values from the database.Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

my database is sql server,but i think it is the same with your question.

if you want to call stored-procedure, you should type you param like `selectAccount(Map map)`. I use this method solve my problem.